# ISPconfig execute php script when email received

Tags: php, email, ispconfig

I wanted to know if there's a way to hook into ISPconfig to fire an event/send a request/execute some PHP whenever a new email comes in.

### Case

I have a small server running Ubuntu and ISPconfig with one domain, and many email address. I'm trying to create an application that allows members to check their mails directly in the app, and send to other members, even if they dont have an email address. So if you'd send an email to iDontExist@domain.com, the given email would be forwarded to the application and stored inside the iDontExist user internal "mailbox".

Is there any way to achieve this ? I didn't find any kind of events or hooks inside ISPconfig.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: I hazard a guess to use PHP to manually open the mailbox and read the contents counting the messages and then rechecking every few seconds.

Comment: But PHP can only read one account at a time, while I want every incoming mail whatever the name looks like to be handled by my script

Comment: that is incorrect (unless I misunderstand you?), if you have 3 users each with their own accounts then PHP can look into 3 different mailboxes one for each user. PHP can also look in multiple mailboxes if you write the code that way.

Comment: Hey I have exactly the same problem, did you find any solution for this?

Comment: I no longer use ISPConfig so can't say. Sorry.

Comment: Did you find a way with another panel? My server should be up and running next year so I'm still considering any solution as the possibility of hooking in the mail process just like you described is a main requirement

Comment: I principly use WHM system which is a paid for variation and in my view fits what I need.